# VMware workstation vs Oracle vm virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, vmware-workstation

I have a Win7 running on my host machine and I want to do some web development using Linux platforms and test some apps on iOS. 
What are the main pros and cons of those to programs. I guess performance wise they should be about the same but maybe one has some functions that  other lacks. In short what are the main differences between VMware workstation vs Oracle vm virtualbox?

Comment: Hmm it looks like a good question to me... Where did you ultimately get your answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obvious difference that one costs money and the other does not, the biggest differentiator that I have found is the depth of support for 3D graphics acceleration and USB device compatibility. VMware wins on both counts.

For typical Web development tasks, both will likely work equally well.